# Looking for Timer.Tick or equivalent on MonoDevelop and GTK

Tags: c#, timer, gtk, monodevelop

Hello there I'm looking for equivalent event for timer.tick from System.Windows.Forms in MS C#  to MonoDevelop C# with GTK...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is `GLib.Timeout.Add (uint interval, GLib.TimeoutHandler handler)`

The interval is expressed in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this:

after parsing all the thingys... then you do something like this to your label or labels:

> **label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString ();**
>
> **Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();**

Apparently the later one is for DATE (Wed. 20th August 2014)... and the first one is for
TIME(2:02:54). Hope you get it.